# Load unrelated models on a route

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-data

I have two models called 'Scenario' and 'Event' that are loaded via a RESTAdapter.

On the 'scenario.index' route I need only the scenarios, but on the 'scenario' route I need a list of all the events so I can present a form to associate them with the scenario shown.

Using the code below, this works if I access directly the 'scenario' route, but not if I first access the 'scenario.index' route and then the 'scenario' route.

What I mean is that ScenarioRoute.model() doesn't get called if I first go to ScenariosIndexRoute.

```
App.Router.map(function()
{
    this.resource('scenarios', function()
    {
        this.resource('scenario', {path: '/:id'});
    });
});

App.ScenariosIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function()
    {
        return this.store.find('scenario');
    }
});

App.ScenarioRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params)
    {
        return {
            scenario: this.store.find('scenario', params.id),
            events: this.store.find('event')
        };
    }
});
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Can we see the declaration of the relationship in the models? Whether the relationship is `async: true` or not might have something to do with this.

Comment: The two models are not directly related, but the problem is not in associating the models. The problem is that ScenarioRoute.model() doesn't get called if I visit ScenarioIndexRoute first. Anyway I have {async: true} on every relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I think the easiest way to accomplish this is to create another route and controller for events, and to hook the scenario controller up with needs on that events controller.

The main reason I think that is because the "best" way to do it is to use Dependency Injection, but that's not exactly simple.

If you're feeling brave, feel free to go have a read of : http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/some-improvement-ideas-for-our-di-subsystem/2378

But as discussed on the forum, was this the thing that worked for you? (for others' future edification):

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function(transition) {
    var self = this;
    var postsController = this.controllerFor('posts');
    if(Ember.isEmpty(postsController.get('allEvents'))) {
      // find returns a promise. We attach a "then" "callback" to it
      // so that "callback" will execute after the store's find promise has resolved
      self.store.find('event').then(function(events) {
        postsController.set('allEvents', events)
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Sweet! :) We should probably add a cookbook entry for this ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd tackle this particular use case:

```
App.ScenarioRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var scenario = this.store.find('scenario', params.id);
    scenario.then(function(scenario) {
      scenario.get('events)
    });
    return scenario;
  }
});
```

That is, you're a promise with another promise chained: store.find returns a promise, which we then use a "then" call on to get the events from the scenario once it has been obtained.

Comment: The events that I want to load are not related to the scenario.

Comment: Duh... so silly of me. I actually knew this at the beginning!